# Rearranging equation help (Doppler shift - special relativity)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having trouble understanding how to rearrange the equation as shown in the picture.

How do I get from:

$\left(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda\right)^{2}(c+V)=(c-V)$

to

$V\left(1+\left(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda\right)^{2}\right)=c\left(1-\left(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda\right)^{2}\right)$

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNDqF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just collect the terms with $c$ to one side and rest to the other side, like
\begin{align}
(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2}(c+V)&=c-V\\
(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2}c+(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2}V&=c-V\\
(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2}c-c&=-V-(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2}V\\
c((\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2}-1)&=V(-1-(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2})\\
c(1-(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2})&=V(1+(\lambda^{\prime} / \lambda)^{2})\\
\end{align}
The book might skip few steps here and there, it is usually expected that the reader will fill in the details.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a=\frac{\lambda'^2}{\lambda^2}$$ then we have
$$ac+aV=c-V$$
so
$$ac-c=-aV-V$$
Multiplying by $-1$
$$c-ac=V(a+1)$$ so we get
$$V=\frac{c(1-a)}{a+1}$$

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear now.